# PHP - CURL - Set-Cookie Header (Ignoring dots)

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to fetch the Set-Cookie value by logging in to an external site and later using this value to perform different actions. I can not save it with CookieJar, I need to return the string from a function.

Anyway. Expected Cookie should look like this : "JSESSIONID=123.cls_rs2a_8009" but I am getting "JESSIONID=123"

So it seems to ignore everything after the dot - OR its not receiving it the same way like a browser does.

Any help on this?

Current code example not showing the URL :

```
$headers = [];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
    function($curl, $header) use (&$headers){
        $len = strlen($header);
        $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
        if (count($header) < 2)
             return $len;

        $name = strtolower(trim($header[0]));
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $headers))
            $headers[$name] = [trim($header[1])];
        else
            $headers[$name][] = trim($header[1]);
        return $len;
    }
);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using Guzzle should be a little easier. From [Guzzle Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies):

```
// Use a specific cookie jar
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
$r = $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/cookies', [
    'cookies' => $jar
]);
```

Fro your example, it seems that you're missing the [headers in response](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

You can also try to get the [full cookies list](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php#118967):

```
curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
```

This migth also come handy: [Guzzle cookies handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835324/guzzle-cookies-handling)

Hope that helps.